# Jquery Galleria Initial Load Problem

Tags: jquery, initialization, loading, galleria

I have set up galleria using full screen theme. I am having this problem that it displays a Blank Screen on the first time the galleria is loaded. When I reload the page is works but only when reloaded not on the initial load.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Any help would be much appreciated as this is needed urgently.

Full code can be viewed here
http://dev.perfectdaycanada.com/fullscreen-galleria/

Thanks Again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code looks suspicious:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (!window.location.search) {
        setTimeout("window.location+='?refreshed';", .1);
    }
}
```

However, I take it that this is your "fix". You have a lot of assets loading in the source, I would suggest that you try loading the theme JS using a script tag and the theme CSS using a link tag in your head. Or you could try the latest build at github, where a theme loading timeout has increased.